# How to use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles

Tags: c#, directory, enumeration

Based on the [documentation on MSDN for `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx), the process involves:

1. declaring `DirectoryInfo` with the path
2. using the `EnumerateFiles` method to retrieve files

There are underlying classes that retrieve this information such as [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) dependent on [`FileSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx).

```
DirectoryInfo DR = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\Downloads");
foreach(FileInfo FF in DR.EnumerateFiles())
{ 
    textBox1.Text += FF.ToString()+ "\r\n"; 
}
```

1. How do I re-code this where I can declare [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) before using it
   directly?
2. How would I re-code this if I were to use `List<T>`?
3. How would I read the list enumerable data?

Thanks

Comment: I am uncertain what you mean in your first question. Do you want a variable holding the list of Fileinfos?

Comment: Why do you need to 'declare FileInfo before using it'?

Comment: i thought that was standard coding procedure? is it not and even if not needed , how would i pre-declare and save the values into a variable or an List<string> Fileinfo?

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(...)` will only return strings (since that's all you're using anyway)

Comment: thanks all, this has got me off to a start. thanks for your inputs, you can close this open ticket as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you want to?
2. `var list = DR.EnumerateFiles().ToList();`

Comment: EnumerateFiles returns an enumerator (an `IEnumerator<FileInfo>`). It represents a sequence of items; they're lazily returned when you use `foreach`. The underlying construct is an iterator block (probably using `yield`).

Comment: question : i wish to learn on all possible ways to read the incoming information from 
 -> enumeratefiles
what is in here , the return is an array  or an object??

how do i read the incoming contents one by one using enumeratefiles ( no particular reason to use this one)

and what is the best possible way to use
1) using var LINQ ( i have no visibility on the contents , i have to give parameters
2) using List<T>, ( i am trying to figure this one) ( can i have an example with List<T>

hope am making some sense here

Comment: thanks all, this has got me off to a start. thanks for your inputs, you can close this open ticket as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not all that clear what you are trying to do, but nonetheless, you can 'declare it before using it', by doing the below:

```
DirectoryInfo DR = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\Downloads");
List<string> filePaths = DR.EnumerateFiles();
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileInfos = filePaths.Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
foreach(FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
{ 
    textBox1.Text += fileInfo.FullName.ToString()+ "\r\n"; 
}
```

(That is, just move the declaration *outside* the foreach loop)

Since `EnumerateFiles` returns the *full path* of the file, so you'd need to create `FileInfo` instances out of that, which you can do using the constructor provided for you.

To do the 'list' bit you've talked about, you just add `ToList()` and LINQ will do the work for you:

```
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = filePaths.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks all, this has got me off to a start. thanks for your inputs, you can close this open ticket as resolved.